# Cloud Database for 10TB of data - most affordable solution

Tags: database, large-data

I feel like I've searched the entire internet on this subject.  I need to create a cloud database which will have 10TB of storage available to it over it's approximate 20 year life.  This storage space takes precedence over read/write performance.  Thus far I've looked at services offered on Microsoft Azure and Amazon Web Services, and unless I'm missing something in the pricing details, they offer no services of this size that are within a reasonable budget.

Can anyone offer advice on the most cost-effective cloud database solution with storage of this size?  Relational vs. NoSQL doesn't really matter, it can be either for the type of data we have.

Comment: I don't understand why people are downvoting this.  I have been researching this for WEEKS.  If you're a serial downvoter, PLEASE consider these 2 things, 1, read the whole post first; 2, try to help out instead of feeling the need to exercise some sort of elitist, self-important lesson-teaching to the community. I don't come here as some lazy person who expects others on the internet to do my work.  This is part of my research, and I NEED this community - my job, at times, depends on the advice I get here.  Sorry for the rant, but ppl are SO quick to downvote what really are viable posts.

Answer (score 1):

its not clear from your question whether you are looking for relational or no sql based databases.

IBM Bluemix has what is called as IBM Cloudant - its a NoSQL database. Here is the pricing calculator - https://www.ibm.com/analytics/us/en/technology/cloud-data-services/cloudant/pricing/index.html

Bluemix also has what is called as Compose - its a Database as a Service offering. As part of Compose, you get MongoDB, PostgresSQL, MySQL, RethinkDB and other databases. Pricing for Compose can be seen here: https://www.compose.com/pricing

BlueMix also has DB2 which is relational. You can find the pricing of DB2 here : https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/db2-hosted?env_id=ibm:yp:eu-gb

Comment: Thank you very much for this information.  I have not looked at IBM's solutions up until now.  This is very useful information which I will explore now.